# How to use http request headers in Got?

Tags: javascript, node.js, https, zomato-api

I have a very simple goal in mind. I want to make an API request from an API known as Zomato from my node.js server application. I'm using an https request framework known as [Got](https://github.com/sindresorhus/got), which is supposed to be a lighter version of request API.

```
var got = require('got');
var httpheaders = {
    'Accept': 'application/json',
    'user-key': '**********************',
    'json': true
}

got('https://developers.zomato.com/api/v2.1/geocode?lat=35&lon=34', {httpheaders}).then(response => {
    console.log('We got something');

    console.log(response.body);

}).catch(error => {
    console.log('We got nothing');
});
```

When I attempt to run this I catch an error and print, "We got nothing". I don't seem to know how to actually include http request headers, but I can't figure out what the proper syntax would be based off the documentation. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: The docs are straight forward: `{headers:httpheaders}`; but that won't help much because you need to understand request headers first: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Request_header

Comment: @RandyCasburn Hey thanks for telling me that is the syntax. Funnily enough that was the first thing I tried when I read the documentation. I thought it was wrong but get this, The API call at lat=35, and lon=34 the whole time is just a straight up 404 error. I called it on the API manually to find that out. I just assumed since lat=36 and lon=34 worked, that lat=35 and lon=34 would work, but nope. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/sindresorhus/got/blob/HEAD/documentation/2-options.md

You could use options, like this

```
import got from 'got';
const options = {
    headers: {
        foo: 'bar'
    }
};
const data = await got(url, options).json();
```